# Trigger operation on entity from operation on another entity Spring data JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a jpa entity say entityA and another entity say entityB that are not have any mapping/association  between them. 
I want to perform some JPQL or operation on entityB when I update or save entityA.
For example say I save new entityA so I want to run some custom JPQL query on entityB or maybe to delete entityB from DB due to the new saving of entityA.
I thought using EntityListener but I don't know how since I don't have entitymanager reference in myh custom EntityListener
How do I do it with Spring JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt a simple trigger on DB side should do the same?
Using Spring, I would suggest you try **@RepositoryEventHandler**

Hope this helps!